# Windows notification with PowerShell: BalloonTipIcon won't show up

Tags: windows, powershell, notifications, tooltip, toast

trying to show a *Toast Notification* on *Windows 11* through **PowerShell** but for some reason the `ToolTipIcon` won't show up.

This is the full code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
$global:balloon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$path = (Get-Process -id $pid).Path
$balloon.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path) 
$balloon.BalloonTipIcon =  [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Info 
$balloon.BalloonTipText = 'Su informe se ha generado.'
$balloon.BalloonTipTitle = "Hola, $Env:USERNAME" 
$balloon.Visible = $true 
$balloon.ShowBalloonTip(5000)
```

The notification shows up but with no icon.

I've tried:

```
$balloon.BalloonTipIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Info
```

And:

```
$balloon.BalloonTipIcon = "Info"
```

Here's a capture of the actual result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think this is related: https://github.com/hardcodet/wpf-notifyicon/issues/65

As your script is working on my Win10.

Note though if you use this type of popup, if the user has turned off notifications they wont see anything.